# No error while writing in a socket without connection

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

I guess that my question is pretty easy for you folks but I can't find a clear explanation to my problem. I have to precise that I'm quite new to c++.

I'm trying to create a really simple TCP Client, using boost::asio socket. I actually have something working with synchronous calls. But at some point, **I stop the connection with my server** (by turning off my wifi), and **the socket continues to write without any error**.

As TCP protocol is supposed to send an ACK message, I believed that the lost of my connection would be detected by a write call.

I read a lot of stuffs about keep_alive, about native sockets and asynchronous writes in every similar questions, but nothing seems to answer to my specific problem.

Here is the part of my code where I try to write and detect lost of connection. Not sure that will help..

```
try {
        boost::system::error_code error;
        boost::asio::write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message), error);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        ReportError(e.what());try {
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message), error);
    if (error) {
        is_server_up = false;
    }
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    ReportError(e.what());
}
    }
```

So my questions are :

- Is there any simple explanation on how to detect writing errors that I missed on the vaste world wide web ?
- Am I using the right functions from boost::asio ?

PS : any comment on how improve my implementation is very welcome !

Comment: Data goes into the TCP IP send window and you won't hear a complaint until the port is formally closed or you overfill the window. In the meantime, TCP is happily trying to send that data and will keep trying until hell freezes over. For all it knows, the network disruption is temporary and will next time it tries the data will be sent.

Comment: any way to make hell freezing really fast then ?

Comment: Not really. TCP is designed to send the data or die trying. You may have to build in a keep alive scheme to detect whether or not you have a connection.

Comment: good to know. the thing is I don't have access to server implementation. So is there a way to use the keep alive feature without changing server code ?

Comment: Correction to myself: If you are sending enough data, you will fill the send window quickly and either get blocked or a "Can't send right now" response  from the write. Not really up on Boost, so I don't know which way it goes.

Comment: @user4581301 This is not correct. Data goes into the socket send buffer, not the 'send window', which is non-existent; and TCP will keep trying to send it until its retry timers expire, which is finite. A send or receive which takes place after that expiry will get an error.

Comment: I'm gonna try to flood the connection and see if I actually get this response at some point. Thanks !

Comment: @EJP Do you have any idea on how I could set this retry timer to a choosen time ?

Comment: @augustin-r I don't believe you can.

Comment: Thse TCP timers are system-wide settings, and they are defaulted to intervals of minutes for a reason, even if that reason sems inappropriate today.  If the network has an alternative route that involves two dial-up modems and a satellite link, it will use it to complete your transfer.

Answer (score 1):

> As TCP protocol is supposed to send an ACK message, I believed that the lost of my connection would be detected by a write call.

Yes, and it will be. But `write` doesn't wait for acknowledgements, that would make applications needlessly slow. The loss of connectivity will be discovered later and eventually reads and writes will fail with errors.

If you performed at least one successful write operation after connectivity was lost, that write will eventually fail. Every read or write operation attempted after that failure occurs will report an error.